# Is there an equivariant simplicial deformation retract of Teichmüller space?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory, outer-automorphisms

Let $S_g$ be a surface of genus $g \ge 2$. By analogy with Teichmüller space for $S_g$, Culler and Vogtmann studied Outer Space $CV_n$, with points projective classes of marked metric graphs with fundamental group free of rank $n$. They showed that $CV_n$ deformation retracts onto its *spine*, $K_n$, which is a simplicial complex. $CV_n$ is "locally" a simplicial complex of dimension $3n-4$, but $K_n$ has dimension $2n-3$ and the action of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ on $K_n$ is properly discontinuous and cocompact. Since $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ has abelian subgroups of rank $2n-3$ and a torsion-free subgroup of finite index, this shows that the virtual cohomological dimension of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ is equal to $2n-3$.

Does Teichmüller space admit a similar equivariant deformation retract whose dimension realizes the virtual cohomological dimension of the mapping class group?

Comment: I think, this is still open (for compact surfaces), see Lizhen Ji's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0877.pdf

Comment: Harer's original proof goes through deformation retract stuff, but I haven't looked through the details(and it sounds like it might not have these bounds)

Comment: I think Ji's paper seems to suggest that Harer's result or something similar is satisfactory when the surface has nonempty boundary? I gave up chasing through the literature at around that point, since the phrasing of everything seemed to suggest the answer is still a "well, not quite"

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Yes, the case of punctured surfaces is settled, the open problem afak is about closed surfaces. If you are satisfies by a contractible space of the right dimension equivariantly homotopy equivalent to the Teichmuller space then the result is again known.